# jQuery tabs programmatically call a URL based tab from within code

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

### Situation

As you can see in the screenshot below, I have an area of my site which makes use of tabs to split up the user dashboard. The tab indexes along the top are declared as URLs and as a result jQuery creates the references at runtime. I would like the user to be able to click the "here for free content" link and the system calls the Free content tab. Let's call that URL "testserver/user/free-content" for the moment
[image: short screenshot]

### Issue

Now, I know how to programmatically deal with this situation when the tabs are declared on page as divs and have static IDs I may assign but, in this case, am not ashamed to say it has me a little stuck before I've even started.
If I set an ID on the link, jQuery will overwrite it so, I can't use that approach.

### Start of solution

What I'm thinking of is the following, sorry that for the moment, I don't have a fiddle, as/if I progress, I'll update the question.

- User clicks the link and jQuery picks up the event by checking if it hasClass('tab-url-call')
- Temporarily save the URL attribute
- Loop through the tab index

  - Check if URL attribute matches the temp stored
  - If matching call this tab
  - **This bit has me at an end of what to do**
- Next

### Update - Extra information

As requested, here is some HTML to demonstrate the current structure

```
<div id="user-tabs" class="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#tab-user-home">Welcome</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="testserver/user/free-content">Free content</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="testserver/user/learning">Learning</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    
    <div id="tab-user-home">
        <h3>You current have freen content "showing"</h3>
        <p>
            This is just an information box to highlight that the user has an
            option set to show free content and inform them that they can 
            reach it via the tab controls or click
            <a
                class="tab-url-call" 
                href="testserver/user/free-content"
            >
            here for free content
            </a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you for taking the time to read my question.

Comment: can you share the html related to the tab? ie the header elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In abstract what you are looking for is

```
//register a click event handler for elements with class tab-url-call
$(document).on('click', '.tab-url-call', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //you need to place the selector for the tab header element here
    //find the anchor element with the same href as the clicked element which is inside the tab header element
    $('tabheader').find('a[href="' + $(this).attr('href') + '"]').click();
})
```